# Every git branch is gone (except master)

Tags: git

I have been trying to delete a hidden file in my directory and accidentally ran the command `rm -rf .??*` which would delete ANY hidden file with more than two characters.  I believe this deleted a file which contains the connections to all the branches because now I only have master as a branch.

```
# my terminal
$ git branch
* master
```

The commands I ran prior to this are:

```
$ rm -rf .DS*
$ rm -rf .??*
$ git add .
$ git add -u
```

Did I really delete a file with all of the repositories?  If so, how do I retrieve it?  If not, why are all the branches I used to have gone?

Edit: I should add, everything is on Github so this isn't a huge problem, but I would rather understand what I did and undo it if possible.

Comment: To test whether by any chance your repo was created as a submodule, you could try `git submodule update --init`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You deleted the `.git` directory which has your repository in, and are just left with the data you had checked out (which happens to be master).

To retrieve it, restore from a backup or another repo that you pushed to.

Comment: That's not what happened; if it was, `git branch` would give `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the command `rm -rf .??*` would remove the `.git` directory. Possibly he has a `.git` directory higher up the FS too.

Comment: I did not see `.git` in the repository at all (as opposed to `.gitignore` which I saw being removed as I ran the command).  However, the directory above this must have a `.git` directory since it responds to `git branch` with `master`, right?

Comment: Every git repository has a .git directory; it's the only thing that makes it a repository at all. What was your working directory when you deleted things?

Comment: The reason I didn't see it may be that I'm looking for hidden files on the left sidebar in SublimeText.  No matter what repository I open, `.git` is not shown in SublimeText.  Still, I believe this to be the correct answer based on Googling how git works.